# Discussion forum

Tags: member

I know this has been discussed a little bit on here, but I'm asking if any one has successfully implemented a Members Discussion Forum using CraftCMS ?

Or, if anyone knows of an add-on roadmap to include this type of functionality ?

I'm really trying to avoid having to use EE to accomplish this.

TIA, Eric

Answer (score 4):

You may want to look at http://vanillaforums.org/  its open source and php based like craft. You host it yourself so no need to worry about a Saas providers longevity (they do offer a hosted option as well at vanillaforums.com)

It has a single sign on option that seems to allow for a basic forum but I havent yet actually tried it, although we have a project coming up this fall that we will likely use it for.

Obviously a custom developed plugin would be the ideal option but that may or may not happen anytime soon.

Answer (score 4):

I would also go the SSO way: Install a nice stand-alone discussion forum and connect it with Craft:

- phpBB ([phpBB3 Cross-site Sessions Integration](https://www.phpbb.com/kb/article/phpbb3-cross-site-sessions-integration))
- Vanilla Forums ([Implementing Vanilla jsConnect Single-Signon](http://blog.vanillaforums.com/help/vanilla-jsconnect-single-signon-on/))
- vBulletin ([SSO Plugin](http://www.vbulletin.org/forum/showthread.php?t=270517))
- Invision Power Board ([Single Sign-On](http://www.invisionpower.com/support/guides/_/advanced-and-developers/integration/single-sign-on-sso-r209))

Answer (score 3):

Just about to start a project where we will be integrating Muut.com, and using their Single Sign-On functionality to make it a pretty seamless experience for our users. Wish I could have native functionality (always worried that any SaaS provider will one day go away), but they look to be the best option.

Answer (score 1):

You might like to check out this alternative http://www.discourse.org/